# Vuetify form not submiting correctly on enter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify form that I am trying to make submit on enter or on button click. I did have this form working on just button click but the enter part is the issue now adding it.

The issue is that it will refresh the page which to me says the default action is being activated. I have tried the below code and also with an explicit action added to the form too. No luck. How can I make this submit on a button click or enter (if the form is valid) and run a method which processes my login?

Template

```
<v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation @keyup.native.enter="submit">
   <v-text-field
    v-model="email"
    :rules="emailRules"
    label="E-mail"
    class="mt-4"
    required
    outlined
   ></v-text-field>
   <v-text-field
    v-model="password"
    :rules="passwordRules"
    label="Password"
    required
    outlined
    :append-icon="show1 ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
    :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
   ></v-text-field>
   <v-btn
    :disabled="!valid"
    color="info"
    block
    class="mr-4"
    type="submit"
    @click="submit"
  >Sign In</v-btn>
 </v-form>
```

submit method

```
submit() {
  this.$refs.form.validate();
  if (this.$refs.form.validate(true)) {
   let email = this.email
   email = email.toLowerCase()
   this.$store.dispatch('login', {
     email, 
     password: this.password
   })
 }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply remove the `type="submit"` from the submit button. You get the undesired submit functionality from it.

Please note that there is a difference in the way Vuetify handles the default type of a button in a form. If the button is a vuetify element `<v-btn>`, the default type is "button", as stated in the [API docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#api-sass), but the default HTML behavior for buttons inside a form is to set the type as "submit", as you can see on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do

`<v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation @submit.prevent="submit">`

When you hit enter or click submit button, submit event is triggered in the form. `prevent` modifier prevents the page from reloading which is builtin in the HTML syntax.

Comment: I had that to start and had no luck with it. The form would not submit except when I clicked the submit button. It worked fine that way but the 'enter' key was useless

Comment: This is working well for me capturing 'enter' key on a `v-text-field`.